# Service Reference Error - netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I was working on WCF service with an endpoint binding of `netTcpBinding`, hosted in a console application.

These are the configuration settings:

```
<system.serviceModel>  
    <services>  
        <service name="FullTimePartTime_EmpWCFServiceAppl.EmployeeService" 
                 behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour" >  
            <endpoint 
                address="EmployeeService" 
                binding="netTcpBinding" 
                contract="FullTimePartTime_EmpWCFServiceAppl.IEmployeeService">  
            </endpoint>  
            <endpoint 
                address="mex" 
                binding="mexTcpBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange">  
            </endpoint>  
            <host>  
                <baseAddresses>  
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7090/"/>  
                </baseAddresses>  
            </host>  
        </service>  
    </services>  
    <behaviors>  
        <serviceBehaviors>  
            <behavior name="mexBehaviour">  
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />  
            </behavior>  
        </serviceBehaviors>  
    </behaviors>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

The console application executes fine. WPF is client app which should consume the WCF service, but when I tried to add a service reference, this error occurred:

[Service Reference Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDRvG.png)

Can anyone help me to fix this issue & let me know the mistake I made?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of sharing an image as a link, showing the text of the error in your question will make it easier to provide an answer.

Comment: I tried to show error image (not as image link) which would give clear idea but Stack Overflow, have minimum reputation restriction.

Comment: Rather than an image, showing the text in your post is best.

Comment: Agreed, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always the metadata discovery is through http.So you need to have one more base address  for the http which publishes the metdata via http.

```
 <host>  
  <baseAddresses>  
 <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7091/"/>  
  <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7090/"/>  
  </baseAddresses>  
 </host>
```

First try to browse the metadata through http://localhost:7091/?wsdl. Now try to generate proxy class using the service reference address http://localhost:7091/.

Comment: Thanks @Hameed Syed, for your comment.